# How do I disregard 0's in a running total/cumulative sum in SQL?

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I'm looking to have my SQL code disregard 0's in a running total. I'm trying to display a graph that is showing `FuelUsed/WH` which includes something like delays which we don't want displayed. We have two earlier select statements one which is work hours into a temp. Another which pulls the other variable "cumulative sum fuel used". This this one `trackingbasisID <> 4` will exclude all delays from the data. But when doing that our data is hopping down to 0 for delays. We then combine these in the main select statement. (I'm leaving out the joins/bulk of the code for the purposes that the whole stored proc this is in is fairly long).

We are displaying this in a line graph so it's going all the way down to zero where we'd like the code to just ignore the 0's and be a steady line that is only considering the numbers above zero / excluding the delay phase `trackingbasis = 4`. Any clue on how to disregard 0's? My solution so far has been to in a statement further down create it so it's turns the 0's into Nulls and this sort of works where it doesn't go down to 0 but it still looks sort of weird/not correct.

```
Select SUM(md.WorkHours) OVER
(ORDER BY md.date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
AS CumulativeSumWorkHours INTO #CumulativeLoadData
FROM V_MechanicalDaily md
WHERE
md.ProjectNumber = @ProjectNumber
and md.PrimePhaseID in (SELECT Value FROM DredgeData.fn_Split(@PrimeP, ',')) 
and md.Date >= @BeginDate and md.Date <= @EndDate
and md.MeasureSystemID = md.ProjUOM
```

Second temp table:

```
Select pltd.ProjectNumber, 
pltd.PrimePhaseNumber, 
pltd.date, 
pltd.PlantNumber,
pltd.FuelUsed as FuelUsed,
SUM(pltd.FuelUsed)
OVER (ORDER BY pltd.date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
AS CumulativeSumFuelUsed,
AVG(pltd.FuelUsed)
OVER (ORDER BY pltd.date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
AS CumulativeAvgFuelUsed
INTO #FuelUsedTable
from V_PLantDetail pltd
INNER JOIN V_ProjectPrimePhase p
on p.ProjectNumber = pltd.ProjectNumber
and p.PrimePhaseNumber = pltd.PrimePhaseNumber
and p.UnitOfMeasureID = pltd.MeasureSystemID
Where 
pltd.ProjectNumber = @ProjectNumber
and pltd.PrimePhaseID in (SELECT Value FROM DredgeData.fn_Split(@PrimeP, ','))
and pltd.PlantNumber = p.PlantNumber and date >=@BeginDate
and date <=@EndDate and pltd.SoftDelete <> 1 and p.TrackingBasisID <> 4
```

In main select statement:

```
fut.CumulativeSumFuelUsed / NULLIF (cum.CumulativeSumWorkHours,0)
AS CumulativeFuelUsedWH, '''
```

Comment: `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default setting. You can remove it for clarity.

Comment: Please add a few rows of the current result set (the bad one), and then how it should look (the desired result set you want).